# I am going to spray water on you

Tags: word-usage

I am looking for a sentence to say when you are in a situation where you want to put some drops of water from your wet hands onto someone else's body, by flickering your fingers. What would be an appropriate verb instead of "to spray"?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Flick

> "I am going to **flick** water on you."
>
> "Stop **flicking** me with water."
>
> "Mum, Sally **flicked** water at me."

I've heard this one used a few times.

Comment: Stop flicking water at your sister, Sally!  :)